# Check if a list contains at least one non-nil element

Tags: lisp, clisp

The title pretty much tells everything.

I am searching for something like

```
(atleastonenonnil '(nil nil nil nil '(A B C)))
=> T
```

I could do it in a recursive way, but I couldn't. Should I use some built-in function?
I'm using `cLisp`

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#some

Answer (score 2):

If you deal with the first element of the list then all the rest can be done recursively.  The code is this:

```
(defun at-least-one-nonnil (l)
  (and (not (nullp l))
       (or (car l)
           (at-least-one-nonnil (cdr l))))))
```

Of course in this simple case there is already a built-in function.

```
(defun at-least-one-nonnil-v2 (l)
  (some #'identity l))
```

but that doesn't help you learn about recursion.

Comment: Aren't both these functions actually at-least-one-nil? To get the desired behavior, you should drop the last not from the first function, and replace `#'not` with `#'identity` in the last. Also, Common lisp uses `(defun function (args) ...)` while `(define (function args) ...)` is scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.( AutoCAD's AutoLisp) Example:

```
(repeat 100000 (setq longlist (cons nil longlist)))
```

then

```
(setq longlist (append longlist (list 1)))
```

this is a 100001 element list with only 1 non-nil element at the end.

```
(apply 'or longlist)
```

returns T. Isn't this the right answer or the list isn't long enough?

Answer (score -1):

what about:

```
(apply 'or '( your list here )) ;; ?
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This has several problems: you can't apply `or` because it is not a function.  If it *was* a function then there is an implementation-dependent limit to the number of arguments a function can take, which might be as low as 50.  So this isn't a solution, and if it was it would be a bad one I'm afraid.

Comment: Works for me.Example: (repeat (setq longlist (cons nil longlist))